# Gulp-livereload, -webserver and -embedlr. How to use them together?

Tags: javascript, gulp, livereload, gulp-watch, gulp-livereload

I try to understand how to use gulp with these useful and popular plugins. There are what I have:

- runned go(lang) server on **localhost:8000**
- static/local html files under **app** folder which are used by server to form pages
- scss files under the same directory, which are converted into css and then autoprefixed

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

// "./" - it's "app" directory
gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('./*.scss')
        .pipe(watch('./*.scss'))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('> 5%'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

So what I need:

- watch html, css/scss files for change and make reload on **localhost:8000** (chrome's open tab)
- it will be great if there is no need to use:

  - livereload chrome plugin
  - expressjs framework
- reload html pages if it opened directly just like file without server

I've read that it is possible to achieve this by using **gulp-embedlr** and **gulp-webserver**. If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the best solution that I find is using Gulp + BrowserSync! It's great solution.

Here is the code of my **gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    reload = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync({
        //logConnections: false,
        //logFileChanges: false,
        notify: false,
        open: false,
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./css/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('> 5%'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./css/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./*.html', reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'sass', 'browserSync']);
```

There is no sense to explain the code above. Just read this: http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/